# I am trying to move the position of grand total row on top in spotfire 7.6. how can i do that?

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to move the position of grand total row on top in Spot-fire 7.6. how can i do that?The grand total row usually appears at the bottom of cross-tab whereas i am trying to move it to the top

Comment: I think this is only possible for subtotals

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible.

one workaround you can use is to create a textarea above the table and use calculated values to show the grand totals.

alternatively, you can do the same with a graphical table above the table.